# Which protocol enforces a transmission time limit?

Tags: transport-protocol, speed

I would like to use an internet protocol for communicating with people in which transmissions are necessarily under 0.1 seconds.

Is there any example of a pre-existing internet protocol where, by design, transmissions occur under a certain amount of time? Maybe it could have applications in certain kinds of networks where a fast transmission is necessary in some way, and hence guaranteed.

Ideally it would be like HTTP where people host text documents and other people request the page.

I would like there to be a mechanism which cancels the transmission if it’s not fast enough. This will force anyone in the network to adapt their web server as necessary. For example, if the server is busy and slow, they will need to load balance, to keep the response fast, if they want their server to be active at all.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like there to be a mechanism which cancels the transmission if it’s not fast enough.

You can do so at the application layer. If the protocol is based on TCP you can likely tap into its timers. Note that APIs, programming and protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off-topic here.

> This will force anyone in the network to adapt their web server as necessary.

You should note that you cannot force transmission time down at will. It's the sum of all forwarding delays (including processing) across switches and routers and the accompanying physical transmission times. Signals move at a finite speed, close to 200,000 km/s for copper and fiber, so a minimum delay of 5 ms per 1000 km is physically impossible to get below. A transmission limit of .1 s limits your geographic reach to roughly 5000 km practically.

Comment: What about via radio? I’m picturing an internet network of radio signals. Even if geographically limited by a certain distance. All I’d have to do is write a protocol with a timer, based on TCP? Thanks

Comment: License-free radio is generally limited to a few dozen or perhaps hundred meters.

Comment: @PeterElbert You would simply send the packet, and if the packet arrives too late, ignore the packet, pretend you didn't receive it. Why someone would want to design a protocol this way, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any example of a pre-existing internet protocol where, by
> design, transmissions occur under a certain amount of time?

There are only two internet protocols: IPv4 and IPv6. The original idea behind the IPv4 TTL field was to limit the time a packet could exist (maximum 255 seconds, or less if starting with a lower TTL). Each hop reduced the TTL by a minimum of one, or more if it took more than one second, and the packet is discarded if the TTL expires prior to reaching its destination.

Neither IP works that way, only reducing the IPv4 TTL (IPv6 Hop Count) by one for each hop, regardless of the amount of time. IP does not take into account any time, and neither are there any types of guarantees. Both IPs are stateless protocols.

Comment: So you’re saying enforcing a time limit would have to happen on the application layer unless someone created a new internet protocol? Why are there only two internet protocols? Hasn’t there been need for some customization and variation? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the first version of IP (IPv4) and its replacement (IPv6) are the only two Internetwork Protocols (IPs), and both are stateless protocols. You could create your own transport protocol (OSI layer-4) to do that, but the IPv4 NAT commonly used would break it, so it would need to use IPv6. The easiest thing would be an application-layer protocol that would need to be used on any hosts/servers where you need this. Whatever you come up with, you should submit as an RFC to the IETF.

Comment: Thanks. Can you think of any examples of highly time dependent network systems? I’m picturing something in finance, cybersecurity, or maybe cloud computing, where the system only has dependability or security if the network is fast and guaranteed. I could try to learn from and model off such an example. Thanks very much

Comment: Even modern trading systems (probably the most time-dependent application I know, where millions of dollars depend on nano-seconds) use IP and deal with time in the application.

Comment: Thanks. We talking WebSockets or what protocol do you have in mind? Or any GitHub repo of such a system? Thanks very much

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: @PeterElbert If there was a way to ask for a really fast packet delivery, *everyone* would put the "please deliver really fast" tag on *all* their packets, so it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: My question was closed on ServerFault but remains open on Quantitative Finance, in case anybody knows the answer. Thanks very much. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/70337/which-network-protocols-do-trading-systems-use-for-speed